# Pointwise Operation with a List of Strings

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nlp, wordnet

I'd like to do a pointwise Operation with a list of strings.
The list contains words (nouns) and could look like this:

```
lst_words = ['car', 'vehicle', 'boat', 'ship']
```

Now I want to do a pointwise operation with this list and get a matrix with the results. The size of the matrix depends on the size of the Input list. (In this case 4x4 values)
The Operation is based within a function what compares the words for similarity and Returns a float number.

The function looks like that:

```
import nltk 
from nltk.corpus import wordnet 
# Compare words:
def get_synset(word_01, word_02):
    w1 = wordnet.synset(word_01 + '.n.01')
    w2 = wordnet.synset(word_02 + '.n.01') 
    return w1.wup_similarity(w2)
```

I wasnt able to find a solution on Google so far but maybe someone can help me to solve this since I dont know what this is called what Im Looking for.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may not be understanding the problem correctly, but why not

```
np.array([[get_synset(x, y) for x in list_words] for y in list_words])
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for! Just for the future, how is something like this called?

Comment: The use of the square brackets to create the list is list comprehension (you have a similar syntax for `dict` and `set`)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `numpy.fromfunction` the only change you'll have to do is change you function to work with indicies of the words instead of the words themselves:

```py
WORDS = ["your", "list", "of", "words"]

def get_synset_by_index(i1, i2):
    return get_synset(WORDS[i1], WORDS[i2])

matrix = numpy.fromfunction(get_synset_by_index, (len(WORDS), len(WORDS))
```